# Import module containing input/output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a python module file (`func.py`) and a unit test file (`f_test.py`):

```
# func.py

def f(x):
    return x + 1

x = input("Enter x: "))

print("f(x): " + str(f(x)))
```

and

```
# f_test.py

import unittest
from func import f

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(f(1), 2)
```

When I run `f_test.py` I expect the test suite to be executed (successfully).
Instead however I see the following input:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... Enter x:
```

If I comment out the input/output lines from `func.py` then I get the expected behaviour.
How do I achieve it without modifying `func.py`?

Comment: How is that not expected? You can't finish importing `func` until all the code finishes running, and the code can't finish running when it's waiting for you to answer the `input`.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to modify func.py, but... You should modify func.py. Use a [`__name__` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) so `x = input` doesn't get executed when you import the module.

Comment: Not just "should", pretty much the only way to avoid modifying func.py would be to install an import hook, or preprocess it and exec the result manually instead of importing it. (Well, I guess you could compile it, dig through it for the compiled code object, construct a function out of it, and run that… But that's not exactly simpler.)

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that running `func.py` is guaranteed to raise a `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` no matter what you type, so… why don't you want to modify it in the first place?

Comment: You can't unit test the functions in func.py because of the problems others have noted. You can execute func.py as a subprocess, pump some data in, and see what you get out. So, if you can't change func.py, you can change the test.

Comment: @tdelaney: Of course what he gets out will be nothing to stdout and a traceback to stderr, so I'm not sure how helpful that will be… but I guess if the point if to properly test his code and fail it for being broken, it will achieve that.

Comment: @abarnert - I guess we can call it test-driven development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you import `func`, all the code inside is run. Running the definition `def f(x)...` is what creates the function `f`.

You can distinguish between importing and running a file by using `if __name__=='__main__'`.

For instance:

```
# func.py

def f(x):
    return x + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = input("Enter x: "))
    print("f(x): " + str(f(x)))
```

When you run `func.py`, `__name__=='__main__'` will be true. When you import it, it will be false (`__name__` will be `'func'` instead).

Comment: In case it isn't obvious to the OP: function (and class, etc.) definitions are code. Compiling the module doesn't create `f`, only running the code in it creates `f`. And Python can't see any difference between 'the code that creates `f`', which you want it to run, and 'the code that waits for input', which you don't; it's all just code.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the correct answer is to modify `func.py`. If you absolutely, positively, won't modify `func.py`, then you could redirect standard input:

```
# f_test.py

import os
import sys
import unittest

oldstdin, sys.stdin = sys.stdin, StringIO.StringIO('7')
try:
  from func import f
finally:
  sys.stdin = oldstdin

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(f(1), 2)
```

Comment: Isn't that just going to raise an `EOFError`, still preventing his code from running?

Comment: I've marked the other answer as correct, but your solution is interesting too, so +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the bottom of f_test.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This way the tests will be executed when the file is run (I forget this more times than I would like to admit).